# Using qt5agg backend with Matplotlib 3.1.2, get_backend() changes behavior

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, pyqt5

I have been using a project which embeds Matplotlib figures in a Qt window and found that it failed when I updated Matplotlib to a version greater than 3.1.0rc1. I have created a minimum working example (`testImports.py`):

```py
import matplotlib

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

f = plt.figure()
x = np.arange(0, 10, 0.001)
ysin = np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x, ysin, '--')
plt.show()
```

With Matplotlib 3.1.0rc1 or earlier, this runs properly, displaying a graph. With Matplotlib 3.1.0rc2 or newer, I get the following error (note that I am working in a virtual environment and I have changed the root of the paths to test_env):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testImports.py", line 14, in <module>
    f = plt.figure()
  File "test_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 534, in figure
    **kwargs)
  File "test_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 3249, in new_figure_manager
    return cls.new_figure_manager_given_figure(num, fig)
  File "test_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 3255, in new_figure_manager_given_figure
    canvas = cls.FigureCanvas(figure)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

I have found that if I include the following lines at the top of `testImports.py`, it works properly for all versions of Matplotlib 3+.

```py
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('qt5agg')
```

So, it seems that something has changed in the way Matplotlib registers backends.

In my testing I also found that having the following at the top of testImports.py solves the problem (without also calling `use('qt5agg')`:

```py
import matplotlib
print(matplotlib.get_backend())
```

That seems very strange to me, since the `matplotlib.get_backend()` function is simply returning a value from a dictionary (from the [source](https://matplotlib.org/_modules/matplotlib.html#get_backend)):

```py
def get_backend():
    """
    Return the name of the current backend.

    See Also
    --------
    matplotlib.use
    """
    return rcParams['backend']
```

**This brings me to my questions:**

1. What changed between Matplotlib 3.1.0rc1 and 3.1.0rc2 that has made it necessary to use the `matplotlib.use()` function prior to importing specific backend functions?
2. Why is calling `matplotlib.get_backend()` drastically changing the behavior of my program, making it unnecessary to call `matplotlib.use()`?

If it helps I am using Python 3.6.9 and Numpy 1.18.0.

**Edit:**
I installed Matplotlib 3.2.0rc2 and am still experiencing the same behavior.

Comment: also if you import `from PyQt5 import QtWidgets` it works correctly.

Comment: Looks like a bug that has been fixed already in the development version, so probably it will not occur any more in matplotlib 3.2

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if what I'm about to describe is the intended behavior of `matplotlib` or a bug. Perhaps the maintainers can weight in.

In essence, `matplotlib.get_backend()` is **NOT** is simply returning a value from a dictionary. In fact, it is triggering a lazy initialization of the "backend" via importing pyplot under the hook, and I can imagine that creating some variations in behavior, since merely calling `import matplotlib` is not sufficient to trigger the initialization (at least in all cases).

When you import matplotlib or any of it's modules, `matplotlib.__init__.py` is implicitly run.
It appears that `rcParams.__getitem__()` is intended to do a lazy initialization of the "backend" if the key value is set to `rcsetup._auto_backend_sentinel`.

When an rcParam object is first constructed, there is no 'backend' key in the dict, even if the desired default value (could depend on matplotlibrc?) is `rcsetup._auto_backend_sentinel`.

These lines of the `__setitem__()` method can involve a situation where `key == backend` and `val == rcsetup._auto_backend_sentinel`, but `backend` is not yet a valid key in the `rcParams(MutableMapping, dict)` object. As a consequence, when the 3rd line `if 'backend' in self:`, which implicitly calls `__getitem__` with a key of 'backend' to check for the presence of the key, gets processed, the lazy initialization of the backend doesn't occur, since the line of `__getitem__` that I've marked "THIS MAY THROW" does in fact throw, and prevent the subsequent lazy initialization.

```py
# Excerpt of rcParams(MutableMapping, dict).__setitem__ from around lines 672
elif key == 'backend':
    if val is rcsetup._auto_backend_sentinel:
        if 'backend' in self:
            return
```

```py
# Excerpt of rcParams(MutableMapping, dict).__getitem__ from around lines 699
elif key == "backend":
    val = dict.__getitem__(self, key) # THIS MAY THROW
    if val is rcsetup._auto_backend_sentinel:
        from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
        plt.switch_backend(rcsetup._auto_backend_sentinel)
```

However, in `__setitem__` the code does succeed in getting `rcParams['backend']` set to `rcsetup._auto_backend_sentinel` (it is normal for `x in X` calls to ignore KeyErrors). So the `rcParams` is populated, but the lazy initialization is yet to be done.

Now when you call `matplotlib.get_backend()` (or other related functions), part of the code path will do `rcParams['backend']`, which this time will actually trigger the lazy initialization in `__getitem__`.

Comment: If you want a quick example to confirm that `matplotlib.get_backend()` function isn't simply returning a value from a dictionary but when first issued actual causes the Qt event loop to generated and tied into the REPL loop, among other things, you can run the following commands in new terminal session: `import matplotlib as mpl`; `from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication`; and confirm `QApplication.instance() is None`. Now "simply" view the backend with `mpl.rcParams['backend']` . If you check again, you'll see that a Qt instance is running as a result of the lazy initialization.